# Overcoming CA2214 "Do not call overridable methods in constructors"

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core, constructor, compiler-errors

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```cs
public abstract class Base
{
    private readonly string _s;
    protected readonly bool _b = getBool();

    protected Base()
    {
        _s = GetS();
    }

    protected abstract string GetS();
}

public sealed class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() : base() {}
    
    protected override string GetS() 
    {
        return _b ? "true" : "false";
    }
}
```

The compiler quite understandably complains with CA2114, since we are calling an overridden method in the base constructor. What is the "best" pattern to avoid this, while having the least impact on the design? I could move the call to `GetS()` and set `_s` into the constructor of `Derived`, but:

- this would mean removing the `readonly` attribute from `_s`;
- creators of subclasses must remember to set `_s` themselves.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't pass the value for `_s` to the `Base` constructor?

Comment: This was my first thought, but its value still has to be computed in the derived class using the value of `_b`

Comment: That raises the question where does _b come from?

Comment: Good question! I've updated the question to show its value being initialized.

Comment: This update to the question does not really show anything. The question has now simply shifted to "where does this `getBool()` come from?" -- Please post a complete, compilable, verifiable example.

Comment: I guess my update is intended to show, it comes from some other black box function.

Comment: Yes but is the blackbox purely from Base or also from Derived (is it also virtual or abstract).

Comment: Let's say its from neither, i.e. it's a static method from another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick patch I suggest turning `_s` *field* into a readonly *property*:

```
public abstract class Base {
  protected readonly bool _b;

  // Backing Field for _s
  private string s_s;

  private string _s => s_s ??= GetS();

  protected Base() {
    _b = true;
  }
 
  // Quick patch: I've kept GetS alive
  protected abstract string GetS();
}
```

As a more elaborated way out I suggest to make the property being `abstract` (please, note that you have field, method and constructor involved into maintaining `_s`; let's combine the relevant code in one property):

```
public abstract class Base {
  protected readonly bool _b;

  protected abstract string _s { get; }

  protected Base() {
    _b = true;
  }
}
```

And then

```
public sealed class Derived : Base {
  public Derived() : base() {}

  protected override string _s => _b ? "true" : "false";
}
```

If (in some class) you don't want to compute `_s` each time, you can perform a lazy computation:

```
public sealed class DerivedHeavy : Base {
  public DerivedHeavy() : base() {
  }

  private Lazy<string> lazy_s = new Lazy<string>(() => {
    // Heavy Computations here...

    return _b ? "true" : "false";
  });

  protected override string _s => lazy_s.Value;
}
```